Python docker: remove unused dependencies to reduce image size
I dockerize an python app that has a dependency on a package that has dependency in numpy, pandas, scipy, etc..
Actually in the actual app only part of that dependencies are actually used.
But when I install the application in dockerfile, all the wheels are downloaded and unpacked. Which leads to an layer of roughly 500MB in size.
I already used pip --no-cache-dir to make it a bit smaller, but of course the unpacked deps are still there.
Can one do some nagic to only keep the actually used modules instead of all those huge packages?
To give more specific example. I use one interpolation method from SciPy. So the SciPy package will be in my site-packages which takes alone 114MB unpacked. Most of this is never used. So I wondered whether there is some option to filter out unnused stuff.
I found an tutorial that suggested to recompile all the packages with removing debug functionallity etc. but that only reduces the size by 40% and in an first attempt caused more problems, because one needs to provide even more build tools like rust etc.

There are multiple solutions for this:

pip cache purge will remove all items from the cache.

Using multi stage build. A first container for installing all the stuff and a final container for copy the wheel files to it.

using virtualenv.

install a package with --user option in pip, so all its files will be installed in the .local directory of the current user’s home directory.




Example:
FROM python:3.11-slim AS build
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --user -r requirements.txt

FROM python:3.11-slim AS final
COPY --from=build /root/.local /root/.local
ENV PATH=/root/.local/bin:$PATH
...


pip3-autoremove can remove a package and its unused dependencies.

Also this answer is interesting in optimizing the requirements. Finally, the best solution for increasing the security and reducing image size is the distroless images.

If I copy the whole .local I end up with the same layer size as before. The .local in the docker has a size of 495MB.

So maybe it is good to optimize the requirements.txt file. If they are still there, it means that they are needed dependencies. I just installed pandas,pandas,numpy to check the size and it was 150MB.

I have myproject as a package and no requirements.txt. The deps are defined in pyproject.toml. The sizes I observe are to be expected: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-shrink-numpy-scipy-pandas-and-matplotlib-for-your-data-product-4ec8d7e86ee4

I propose add all your dependencies to poetry instead of having both. Also the URL is for 6 years ago, so the size changes unless you are using the same version.

What both? I have a packaged project and define all deps in pyproject.toml. There is no need for requirements.txt, nor poetry. Of course the sizes have changed, but not that much at all.
